# How to change the text color of only one row in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs, formatting, grid

I've created the following ExtJS grid.

I want to change the text color of all the cells in the **second** row.

However, I can only find out how to change the color of **all** cells in **all** rows including the header text, as show here:

```
var myData = [
    [4, 'This is a whole bunch of text that is going to be word-wrapped inside this column.', 0.24, 3.0, '2010-11-17 08:31:12'],
    [16, 'Computer2-this row should be red', 0.28, 2.7, '2010-11-14 08:31:12'],
    [5, 'Network1', 0.02, 2.5, '2010-11-12 08:31:12'],
    [1, 'Network2', 0.01, 4.1, '2010-11-11 08:31:12'],
    [12, 'Other', 0.42, 5.0, '2010-11-04 08:31:12']
];

var myReader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'object',
        type: 'object'
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        type: 'float'
    }, {
        name: 'rank',
        type: 'float'
    }, {
        name: 'lastChange',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    }]);

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    region: 'center',
    style: 'color:red', //makes ALL text in grid red, I only want one row to be red
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        data: myData,
        reader: myReader
    }),
    columns: [{
            header: 'ID',
            width: 50,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'id',

            hidden: false

        }, {
            header: 'Object',
            width: 120,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'object',
            renderer: columnWrap

        }, {
            header: 'Status',
            width: 90,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'status'
        }, {
            header: 'Rank',
            width: 90,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'rank'
        }, {
            header: 'Last Updated',
            width: 120,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    title: 'Computer Information',
    width: 500,
    autoHeight: true,
    frame: true,
    listeners: {
        'rowdblclick': function(grid, index, rec){
            var id = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().json[0];
            go_to_page('edit_item', 'id=' + id);
        }
    }
});
```

**What do I have to do to change the text color of only the cells in the second row?**

Comment: No offense to Lionel intended, but you don't want to do it that way. You want to use getRowClass to implement that logic -- that's why it's there. His edit even says that his method would fail if your store retrieves data remotely.

Comment: Depends on how generic he wishes to achieve. If all he need is a  dirty hack, then that's the one. If he need a long term fix, yours is better. :)

Comment: Haha I kind of agree, except dirty hacks tend to come back and bite you in the butt one day. I'd rather do it the "right" way first and be done with it -- especially if he'll later need to add more styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if this helps, but you can try. I tried locally, it does change the color of all the characters in 2nd row.

Add listener to the grid:

```
listeners:{
    viewready: function(g){
        g.getView().getRow(1).style.color="#f30";
    }
}
```

"When `viewready`, you can get the row's div by using `getRow()` method from `GridView`. After that is normal Javascript of assigning colors (or adding extra class, if you want)

Cheers

**EDIT**

I realize it's not working if your store is retrieving data remotely. View is ready but data is not ready. This method would fail.

Comment: You would probably need to use this listener to add on`load` listener to grid's store: `viewready: function(g) {g.getStore().on('load',function(s) {g.geView().getRow(1).style.color ="#f30";}}`

Answer (score 8):

You want to override `getRowClass`, which is passed into the GridPanel's `viewConfig`. An example is provided in GridPanel's API docs:

```
   viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true,

   //   Return CSS class to apply to rows depending upon data values
        getRowClass: function(record, index) {
            var c = record.get('change');
            if (c < 0) {
                return 'price-fall';
            } else if (c > 0) {
                return 'price-rise';
            }
        }
    },
```

`GridView` contains the method, so look there in the API for more information:

```
getRowClass( Record record, Number index, Object rowParams, Store store )
```

> Override this function to apply custom
>   CSS classes to rows during rendering.
>   You can also supply custom parameters
>   to the row template for the current
>   row to customize how it is rendered
>   using the rowParams parameter. This
>   function should return the CSS class
>   name (or empty string '' for none)
>   that will be added to the row's
>   wrapping div. To apply multiple class
>   names, simply return them
>   space-delimited within the string
>   (e.g., 'my-class another-class').

You can apply the CSS to a certain row by using the `index` argument.