# What would be causing g.getView().getRow(0).style.color="red" not to function in ExtJS Grid?

Tags: extjs, formatting, grid

I was able to color specific rows of a ExtJS grid with the code below which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782276/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-only-one-row-in-an-extjs-grid/4782425#4782425):

[image]

However, in the actual application, the exact same code does not show the colors:

[image]

The difference is that in the second example, the code is being loaded via AJAX into a larger application, and so it is difficult to debug it with Firebug.

I'm sure execution gets inside the **viewready** function since I can put an alert in there and see that it is executed but the `g.getView().getRow(2).style.color='red';` is not being executed for some reason (or is being reset for some reason).

The `myData` variable is the same in the second example as in the first (not being loaded from an external source), the applicatoin simply builds this javascript code with PHP.

**What could be the cause of the test example working by itself but this code not functioning within the larger application?**

```
var myData = [
    ['newfile.csv', 'CSV', 15313, '2011-01-24 09:49:55', 'newfile', '2011-01-24 14:40:21', 'auf letztem Stand'],
    ['test333.csv', 'CSV', 15313, '2011-01-24 09:49:56', 'test333', '2011-01-24 14:40:19', 'auf letztem Stand'],
    ['test.xls (sheet1)', 'XLS', 7168, '2011-01-24 09:49:56', 'test__sheet1', '2011-01-24 14:40:23', 'auf letztem Stand'],
    ['test.xls (sheet2)', 'XLS', 7168, '2011-01-24 09:49:56', 'test__sheet2', '2011-01-24 14:40:25', 'auf letztem Stand'],
    ['test.xls (Tabelle3)', 'XLS', 7168, '2011-01-24 09:49:56', 'test__Tabelle3', '2011-01-24 15:35:07', 'auf letztem Stand']
];
var myReader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'kind',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'file_size',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'when_file_copied',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        type: 'date'
    }, {
        name: 'table_name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'when_table_created',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        type: 'string'
    }]);

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    region: 'center',
    style: 'margin: 10px',
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        data: myData,
        reader: myReader
    }),
    columns: [{
            header: 'Worksheets zum importieren',
            width: 300,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            header: 'Typ',
            width: 50,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'kind'
        }, {
            header: 'Größe (bytes)',
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'file_size'
        }, {
            header: 'Wann Datei kopiert',
            width: 150,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            dataIndex: 'when_file_copied'
        }, {
            header: 'MySQL Tabellenname',
            width: 300,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'table_name'
        }, {
            header: 'Wann Tabelle erstellt',
            width: 160,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'when_table_created'
        }, {
            header: 'Status',
            width: 300,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'status'
        }],
    viewConfig: {
    },
    title: 'Gültige Dateien (.csv und .xsl/.xslx unter 4MB) in Importverzeichnis (webdev: /data/storage/test/original_excel)',
    width: 1300,
    listeners: {
        'rowdblclick': function(grid_smart_worksheets, index, rec){
            var id = grid_smart_worksheets.getSelectionModel().getSelected().json[0];
            replace_region_with_uri_content('backend/application/importmanager/single', targetRegion, 'id='+id);
        },
        'viewready' : function(g) {
            g.getView().getRow(0).style.color="red";
            g.getView().getRow(2).style.color="#aaa";
        }
    },
    autoHeight: true,
    frame: true
});
```

## Answer

Gajahlemu's code below works well as it is in my demo but in my application I had to modify the CSS applying it to the inner `TD` to avoid conflicts with other styles, so this works for example:

```
.grid-row-highlight td {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the answer you link to is a hack? I've already provided the method to use when applying styles to individual rows in your previous question. Why don't you give it a go and let us know if that works or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a simple hack for simple app. If you plan for remote store please use McStretch implementation. Sorry for the confusion made earlier. I thought that would be a simpler hack for a local app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider this:
Your data is loaded remotely (using ajax) or your data is to large because of that might be there was a time lag between data loading and data rendering so the call for viewready handler function could be fail in

```
g.getView().getRow(2)
```

because the "row" is not there yet (undefined)

try use [McStretch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782276/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-only-one-row-in-an-extjs-grid/4782515#4782515) solution its much better. Here is my example how to implement that:

```
....
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){ 
        if(rowIndex == 2){
            return 'red-row';
        } else {
           return '';
        }
    }
},
title: 'Gültige Dateien (.csv und .xsl/.xslx unter 4MB) in Importverzeichnis (webdev: /data/storage/test/original_excel)',
width: 1300,
listeners: {
    'rowdblclick': function(grid_smart_worksheets, index, rec){
        var id = grid_smart_worksheets.getSelectionModel().getSelected().json[0];
        replace_region_with_uri_content('backend/application/importmanager/single', targetRegion, 'id='+id);
    },
},
....
```

P.S: Don't forget to declare class "red-row" in your css file or between `<style>` tag i.e

```
.red-row {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event after store load your data ( 'dataloaded' ), have grid responded to it by changing colors like now with 'viewready'